# Joining 3 MySQL tables in to 1 query

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables which store user, available settings and user settings.
User table has standard user stuff like username, password, name, date etc.
Settings table has a list of all available system settings and a default value like:

```
settingID   name                  defaultValue
----------------------------------------------
1           push notifications    1
2           profile image         0
3           full name             1
4           distance measure      Miles
```

User setting table has any custom settings set by the user like so:

```
userSettingID    userID    settingID    customValue
----------------------------------------------------------
1                1         1            0
2                1         3            0
3                1         4            KM
```

I am trying to make a query that will join all 3 tables together however produce ALL results from the settings table and if there is a match in the userSettings table use the customValue otherwise use the defaultValue from the settings table.

So I would like to produce the below:

```
userID   settingID   userSettingID   name     defaultValue   customValue
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        1           1               push...  1              0
null     2           null            profi..  0              null
1        3           2               full...  1              0
1        4           3               dista..  Miles          KM
```

As you can see I would like EVERY setting record and if there are matches populate with userID and/or customValue otherwise fill with NULL.

I was able to get the desired results but as soon as I add a WHERE userID = x clause I only get records that a user has been set to.

Thanks

Edit: The query I have so far is:

```
SELECT *
FROM settings
LEFT OUTER JOIN userSettings ON settings.settingID = userSettings.settingID
LEFT OUTER JOIN user ON userSettings.userID = user.userID
```

Comment: Edit your question and include the query that you have written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `customValue` instead of the `defaultValue` if it is present you can use the `coalesce` function and to filter by `userid` you'll want to add the condition to the join instead of using it in a where clause (which would make the left join behave like an inner join).

I'm guessing you want something like this:

```
select 
    us.userID, 
    s.settingID, 
    us.userSettingID,
    s.name, 
    s.defaultValue,
    us.customValue,
    coalesce(us.customValue, s.defaultvalue) as OverriddenValue
from settings s
left join Usersetting us on s.settingID = us.settingID 
left join user u on u.userid = us.userID and u.userID = 1
```

`user` is a non-reserved keyword in MySQL and as such isn't a good choice for an identifier, although it is permitted to be used without quoting.

Comment: Thanks for this. It seems to work OK however if there is another user (say user 2) that has a setting that user 1 does not, user 1 inherits users 2 custom setting instead of using the default.

Comment: @puks1978 Oh right. I misunderstood. Try this: `select *, coalesce(us.customValue, c.defaultvalue) 
from (select * from users, settings) c
left join Usersetting us on us.settingID = c.settingID and us.userID = c.userid where c.userid = 1`

Comment: PERFECT! Thanks so much.